# Overlay 10K polygon SVG on Google Map (existing answers don't work)?

Tags: google-maps

How do I overlay an SVG with 10K polygons on google maps? Notes:

- Drawing 10K polygons client-side is painfully slow.
- Converting to kmz and using as a KML layer fails because of Google 
  Map's limits on KML filesize and/or number of polygons.
- My current solution is converting pieces of the SVG to PNG on 
  demand. This [works](http://test.barrycarter.info/gettile2.php), but 
  is slow, even for the very simple SVG I parse there (the example 
  doesn't have 10K polygons, just an example of the SVG -> PNG 
  technique). Source code for SVG -> PNG thing: https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-mytile2.pl

Is there a better way? I know there are other answers to this problem 
here, but I believe they use client-side drawing or Google Map's KML 
layer, neither of which would work for me here.

EDIT: I realize caching may help some, but I can't cache every single tile, and my sense is that people browsing will zoom in on different parts of the world.

Comment: Are all the polygons visible at once?  If not I'd try and only draw those that would be visible in the current viewport, and update that dynamically as the bounds change.  Possibly using AJAX to get the polygons rather than have to create an array of 10K items that might not all be used

Comment: Thanks, duncan. When viewing the entire world, all 10K polygons are theoretically visible, though some may be too small to render. However, I suspect that finding which ones are too small would be computationally intensive. Is there a fast way to intersect a set of polygons with a cropping rectangle? Note: someone else noted that drawing even 127 polygons client-side is slow, and there are definitely more than 127 polygons visible at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Generate and cache png map tiles for low zoom levels. On higher zoom levels, overlay polygons client side, but process/download visible polygons only. Consider reducing number of polygon points depending on zoom level.